# analyzing heap dump with eclipse memory analyser

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, memory-leaks

I have generated a heap dump into a file using the jmap command and I am doing memory analysis using Eclipse Mars. I am basically trying to figure out the memory leak in Tomcat 8. Whenever, I start Tomcat 8, I keep on getting the `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` in the tomcat logs and hence I am doing all this to figure out the leak.

I can see the following report(screenshot) in eclipse but I am unable to figure out how to fix this problem. Please let me know if more screenshots are needed.

[image]

Another thing I have tried before performing above steps :

I set up a `setenv.bat` file and included the following instructions in it :

`set JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

However, this thing didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you elaborate it more? The leak might be occurring because of your deployed applications

Comment: Yes, it started recently. When I was deploying WAR file in the ROOT of Tomcat.

Comment: Could you look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded if it helps